# Read words from mp3 file with C#

Tags: c#, cpu-word, mp3, extract

I want to write a program that will take a mp3 file as a input and output will be the words that are available in that mp3 file. For example, I have a file name test.mp3, that contains some sentences (e.g. how are you? I am fine. What is your name?), now I want to parse the mp3 file so that I can get all words/sentence that are available in test.mp3 file. I prefer .NET(c#) code.

If file format is .wav, then It is okay for  me.

Please help me about the issue.

-Thanks,
 Arefin

Comment: This is a too high level question, you should be more specific. For now, you could google "c# Speech Recognition".

Comment: #1 concept - your mp3 file does not 'contain' any words. It only contains a compressed waveform (and maybe some meta data). The leap from audio waveform to human speech recognition is a vast area of research, and is still not an exact science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx . Maybe you'll find something there.